# Get image from IP camera

Tags: android, sockets

I am trying to get Image from the IP camera (onvif) in my android device. 
http://192.168.0.10/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?stream=1

```
<pre>

 Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

//        http://192.168.137.10/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?stream=1
        builder.scheme("http")
                .authority("192.168.0.10")
                .appendPath("cgi-bin")
        .appendPath("snapshot.cgi")
        .appendQueryParameter("stream","1");
                ;

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
        request.setURI(new URI(myUrl));

//        public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(myUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
//                return myBitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
//                return null;
            }
</pre>
```

I am receiving timeout error while connect. Is there any other way to download the images from IP camera.

Comment: That's a local IP address. Are you trying to connect to it from within the same network?

Comment: yes I am trying in local network